# Error using docker-compose down

Tags: docker-compose

I found such command as `docker-compose down` on docker [website](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/), but when I try to use it i get an error.

```
No such command: down

Commands:
  build              Build or rebuild services
  help               Get help on a command
  kill               Kill containers
  logs               View output from containers
  port               Print the public port for a port binding
  ps                 List containers
  pull               Pulls service images
  restart            Restart services
  rm                 Remove stopped containers
  run                Run a one-off command
  scale              Set number of containers for a service
  start              Start services
  stop               Stop services
  up                 Create and start containers
  migrate-to-labels  Recreate containers to add labels
```

My docker-compose version is:

```
docker-compose version: 1.3.1
CPython version: 2.7.10
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
```

Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that `docker-compose down` command is not available in the version you use - the command was added in version `1.6.0` - see the [CHANGELOG here](https://github.com/docker/compose/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#160-2016-01-15).
So if you really want to use the command, you may have to upgrade to version `1.6.0` or later.

Hope this helps.